# Getting null pointer exception while reading excel file data

Tags: apache-poi

```
@Test
public void dataProviderMethod() throws InvocationTargetException, FileNotFoundException 
{
    try
    {
        File src=new File("D:\\TestData.xls");
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);
        HSSFWorkbook wb=new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        int rowcount=sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;

        System.out.println(rowcount);

        for(int i=1; i<rowcount;i++)
        {
            String questionType=sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue().toString();
            System.out.println(questionType);
        }

    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please read the manual? [Iterate over rows and cells](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterate+over+rows+and+cells) and [Iterate over cells, with control of missing / blank cells](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterate+over+cells%2C+with+control+of+missing+%2F+blank+cells).

Comment: And what to do if I get `NPE`? Looking at `API` docu whether some methods may return `null` -> [Sheet.getRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow-int-) as well as [Row.getCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell-int-) may return `null`. So we have to check whether the row is `null` befor using it further. Same with the cell.

Comment: after reading I have to pass that value to the  respective class which will be the possible solution

Comment: if I got questionType = Slider then I have read the only weight value and weight unit with value then I have to pass slider class. which will be possible solution. Using only normal for loop , so unable to handle that exception. If I use iterator then how to pass only that value to slider class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the code logic as below. Since, Some of the cell has blank value and hence null pointer exception is throwing. We need to handle the NULL Cell Value as below

**Modified For loop Code:**

```
    //Column Index
    int column=0;
    for(int i=1; i<rowcount;i++){
        Row r=sheet.getRow(i);
        Cell c=r.getCell(column, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);

        if(c==null){
            questionType="";
        }
        else{
             questionType=r.getCell(column).getStringCellValue();
        }
        System.out.println(questionType);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Subburaj. Now its working for me.

Comment: Glad to know,it helped. Please accept the answer and give the upvote!!!

Comment: @Subburaj- Is it possible. Like question type is matched then i want to read only respective label and value, store it in array object (or any possible way) then i have to pass that object to respective class

Comment: Yeah. we can retrieve only the matched questions label and value in some array list.But some additonal logic needs to be added to extract question type specific label and value(Matched Question Type start and end index needs to be calculated)

Comment: @Subburaj- can you please help on this logic. ?

Comment: Yeah Sure. Please raise it as separate question. I will help you on that

Comment: @Subburaj- Please check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682008/error-in-for-loop-with-while-reading-excel-file-in-hashpmap

Comment: @Swapnil bargale : I have given the answer for the above question. Please give the upvote for both the answers